# Create a function in SQL to extract data as per Date

Tags: sql, r

I have a data/table in SQL that has almost 2 million rows of data. I need to import to R and build a application in R shiny. It is impossible to import all rows in a single go. So can we create a function in SQL so that we can give a parameter as Date to import. For example

```
table1 has 20,00000 rows
ColA   Date        Col C
a      2012-01-01    4
b      2013-01-01    5
c      2014-01-01    6
.
.
.
.
d     2020-01-01     7
```

Create a function in SQL so that

```
table1('from date', 'to date') #  to give only filtered data
```

I know I can use where clause but even that takes time.

Comment: For the international audience, a lakh is 100K; this table has 2M rows

Comment: So tell me; is this homework? Or maybe the job spec posted on fiverr? Just seems a bit odd the way you tell us to "create a function" - it's like what an assignment would say...

Comment: Nope. This is something I want to learn. I am new to SQL

Comment: (1) Creating *SQL functions* varies by the DBMS, and since there are many "prominent" DBMSes out there, the likelihood of somebody writing a function for you for your model and version is fairly low. You need to be more specific. (2) If you want a SQL function, why do you add the [tag:r] tag? (3) Do you just need help formulating a SQL *query* that you can use from R? If that's the case, then ... `SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE Date BETWEEN fromdate AND todate` should do it. You can wrap that in your preference of `DBI` or `dbplyr` or `RODBC`.

Comment: Your assertion that *"where clause ... even that takes time"* suggests that your query might not be hitting the "index" of the table in the right way. For instance, I have a 400 million row table, and if I query by the "Id" field, it takes 10 minutes to retrieve the 10 rows I need (literally); if I include conditions on "time" and "otheridfield", the same 10 rows take under 10 seconds. If `table1` is that large, then you would be well-informed to know which fields "should" be used (for filtering) in your queries.

Comment: Makes sense . Thanks I’ll try.